Allow only a subset of react HTML elements
I am building a React UI library for internal use, where i defined my own Button, Modal, Text and all common components.
I would like to allow only a subset of the HTML tags to be available when using this library.
For example, I do not want other developers to use the  tag, to ensure consistency.
It's fine just a type error, nothing more.
So far my best shot is
declare module "react" {
  namespace JSX {
    type OriginalIntrinsicElements = Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements, "button">;

    interface IntrinsicElements {
      button: undefined;
    }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button>My Button</button>
      <random></random>
    </div>
  );
}


Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-subset-2hm3qz
It kinda works, but "button" components gives a different error than "random".
Type '{ children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
while random
Property 'random' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.typescript(2339)
Is there a way to completely remove "button" from "IntrinsicElements", instead of forcing an undefined?
Thanks
EDIT: I would like to avoid patch-package if possible. I don't know if that can causes build error on third party packages
